# Toggle iconName in lightning:buttonIcon Salesforce lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-experience

On click of a button Iwant ot toggle the IconName in lightning:buttonIcon tag in Lightning component. I want to toggle the iconName from **utility:success** to **utility:error**, is there any way to do it?

Here is my lightning:buttonIcon with iconName

`<lightning:buttonIcon iconName="utility:success" size="small" />`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You just use a normal attribute, and toggle it as you need to. Self-contained example follows:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">
    <aura:attribute name="icon" type="String" default="utility:success" />
    <lightning:buttonIcon iconName="{!v.icon}" title="Default" alternativeText="Default"
                          onclick="{!c.click}" />
</aura:application>
```

---

```
({
    click: function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.icon",
                      component.get("v.icon")=="utility:success"?
                      "utility:error":"utility:success");
    }
})
```

Comment: you are just awesome, didn't thought this approach, thanks allot.

Comment: @AbhiTripathi No problem, glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

Alternative solution where you can set any component value using javascript:

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds" >
<lightning:buttonIcon aura:id="firstButton" iconName="utility:success" title="Default" alternativeText="Default"/>

<lightning:button label="Toggle Icon" onclick="{!c.toggleIcon}" />
```

JS

```
({
    toggleIcon: function(component, event, helper) {

        component.find("firstButton").set("v.iconName",'utility:error');
    }
})
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this addresses the question of how to toggle a button's icon.  Toggle implies a continual change of state based on the user clicking something.  If I am reading your example correctly, there's just a one-way state change from "success" to "error", not a true toggle.